# How to inset a curve into section of circle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I apologise if this is a duplicate, I have no idea what to google.

Here is my circle section:
[image: Circle Section]
I have used an array around a rotated empty axis to retain symmetry.
How would I inset a curve into this section, so a circle is inset into the whole object? Here is an example image because I am bad at explaining things:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want a result like the second image? Or are you trying to achieve something similar only in that circle's section?

Comment: I want a result like the second image, but using the array modifier. This is probably a better example: https://i.imgur.com/3ByNYGj.png

Comment: Ok so the actual mesh is only that section, right? the rest is repeated by the array modifier i guess.

Comment: Yes, sorry for showing it poorly

Comment: Not the most elegant, but I think you can get what you want by (1) select the curve you want to inset, (2) extrude in place (extrude then hit Esc), (3) choose Select-->Inverse (Ctrl-I), (4) manually deselect the circle's origin point (Shift-click it), (5) use an edge slide (G-G) to reposition the "inner" arc/curve.  For #5 you could also "scale" as long as you set the transform origin/pivot center to the circle's origin point, e.g. by putting the 3D cursor there.

Comment: The edge slide didn't do anything, but the scale worked. Thanks a ton, you might want to post that as an answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to obtain the result you want could be to select the edges in the mesh I selected in the image below and simply click on "Subdivide" in the Tools panel on the left. You should obtain something like the second image, which looks similar to the one you posted in the comments. Remember that you have to do this before using the array modifier, so either hide it by clicking on the eye icon in the modifier panel or delete it and make a new one from the beginning, after you obtained the result you want with the original mesh.

[image: edges]

[image: subdivided]